# How to get the id of recently registered user from database?

Tags: database, user-meta, users

I just want to get the ID of the recently registered user using my custom created registration form.

Here is my code.

```
 $user_id = wp_insert_user( array ('first_name' => 
    apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $first_name), 'last_name' => 
    apply_filters('pre_user_last_name', $last_name), 'user_pass' => 
    apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $pwd1), 'user_login' => 
    apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username), 'user_email' => 
    apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );

   if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
        $err = 'Error on user creation.';
   } else {
        do_action('user_register', $user_id);
        $success = 'You\'re successfully register';
   }
```

What I was planning to do - store the registration entries into session and look for users with the same email address (email won't duplicate here) and get the ID of it. I don't know if it is the best practice to follow.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The `wp_insert_user` should return you the user id if the user is created. You should check if the email already exists before you insert the user. wordpress have a function for this `email_exists()` also check if the username is exists `username_exists()`

Comment: Why are you adding the entry to the session? Did you want to log in the user after they register?